# Does not enter the function - python

Tags: python, django-models

I'm having difficulty with this code:

```
class Purchases(TimeStampedModel):
    values = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, default=0)
    cpf = BRCPFField("CPF")
    validated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    clashback = 0

    def calculation_clashback(self):
        if self.values <= 1000:
            self.clashback = (self.values * 0.1)
            return self.clashback

        elif self.values >1000 and self.values <=1500:
            self.clashback = (self.values * 0.15)
            return self.clashback

        elif self.values >1500:
            self.clashback = (self.values * 0.20)
            return self.clashback
```

It is returning zero clashback, it is not entering the function to calculate the clashback. Can someone help me?

I would like it to return the clahsback with the percentage of the value, equal to the function

Comment: Well you never call it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By defining a method, it will not trigger that method: you need to *call* the method, or some logic in the model needs to do that. But just defining a method is *not* sufficient. Likely it is better to work with a `@property` here and thus determine the `cashback` when needed. This thus looks like:

```
from decimal import Decimal

class Purchases(TimeStampedModel):
    values = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, default=0)
    cpf = BRCPFField("CPF")
    validated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    @property
    def clashback(self):
        if self.values <= 1000:
            return self.values * Decimal('0.1')
        elif self.values <= 1500:
            return self.values * Decimal('0.15')
        else:
            return self.values * Decimal('0.20')
```